# kaa_profile.h in generated SDK

Tags: kaa

Run into the following problem while running test program on `Kaa SDK` in `C`:

> "[ERROR] [kaa.c:233] (-18) - Profile isn't set"

Try to initialize the `"Profile"` but can't found `profile.h`. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The 'profile' is a Kaa extention and thus is located separately:

https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/extensions/profile/kaa_profile.h

You might find examples on the extention(s) usage in the [Kaa Sample Application](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps) repository on GitHub. Also, try [Kaa Sandbox](https://www.kaaproject.org/download-kaa/) that was specially developed for fast and easy startup with Kaa.

Comment: Which application demonstrates how to use the 'profile' extension?